# How to make an optimal hibernate query with three objects?

Tags: hibernate, orm, hql

I have a query but I don't know how to make it optimal. I have three objects.

- SCP
- Question : it has a field that points SCP (SCP_id)
- Answer : it has a field that points Question (question_id)

How can I make a query that counts the number of answer within a given SCP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
select count(a) 
from Answer a 
where a.question.scp.id = :id
```

Which generates the following SQL:

```
select
  count(answer0_.id) as col_0_0_ 
 from
  Answer answer0_,
  Question question1_ 
 where
  answer0_.question_id=question1_.id 
  and question1_.scp_id=?
```

Seems pretty efficient.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Would it be more efficient to use denormalization ?

Comment: @user284237 The query is doing **one** join, I wouldn't bother.